# Numpy Array replace booleans with string depending on position of "True"

Tags: python, numpy

To process to output of a multi-class classification I'd like to process a numpy array in such a way, that every `True` from the first column results in a `class1` and a `True` in `class2` correspondingly. A row with no `True`'s should be translated into `class3`.

My initial array looks like that:

```
[[True False],
[False False],
[False True],
...
[True False],
[False True]]
```

(A row containing [True True] can not arise.)

What I'd like to get out is:

```
[class1 class3 class2 ... class1 class2]
```

Ideas for an elegant and fast approach are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

```
import numpy as np
cls = np.array([[True, False],[False, False],[False, True],[True, False],[False, True]])

mask = cls.any(-1)
condlist = [(mask & cls[..., 0]), 
            (mask & cls[..., 1]),
            (mask==False)]
choicelist = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']
res = np.select(condlist, choicelist, 'Not valid')
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['class1' 'class3' 'class2' 'class1' 'class2']
```